# Input 12 digit number and save as int. C

Tags: c, memory, digits

I am new to C and memory allocation. I am trying to take a 12 digit input and save as int so later on I can do some calculations. So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){
    char number[12];
    do
    {
        printf("Credit Card Number: ");
        scanf("%lli", number);
    } while (number == 1);
    
    printf("%lli", number);
}
```

Right now I use long long int since I can use 64 bits, but when I run it and type in 123 I get:

```
27583791809822484
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong, why the output is 27583791809822484 and if I have any styling errors.

Comment: `char number[12]` is a character array, not a long long int

Comment: You need `char number[13]` to hold a 12-digit number. You need room for the null terminator.

Comment: A credit card number may be *called* a "number", but it's really not. And it's not something one does "calculations" on. Unless you mean to calculate the checksum for which you need he digits one by one, for which the character array you have is enough, ***If*** you read is as an array of characters (one by one).

Answer (score 3):

`scanf %lli` expects a pointer to a `long long int`. You provided a pointer to an array of 12 char.

`printf %lli` expects a `long long int`. You provide a pointer.

```c
long long int card_num;
scanf("%lli", &card_num);
printf("%lli", card_num);
```

---

If you wanted to portable code, you'd use

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t card_num;
scanf("%" SCNu64, &card_num);
printf("%" PRIu64, card_num);
```

---

If you wanted to store the number as a string (which is quite reasonable for a credit card number), then `char number[12]` makes sense, but you'd use `%s`. Actually, it would have to be `char number[13]` to be large enough to store 12 digits and the trailing NUL.

```c
char card_num[13];
scanf("%12s", card_num);
printf("%s", card_num);
```

Comment: Sorry, got called away and posted less than I meant to. I've added the remainder.

Comment: The width specifier for `scanf` does not account for the nul terminator, unlike most other functions. Therefore, you need to use `%12s`. The function will write at most 12 characters and then it will append an extra nul. You array must always have a size of at least `width+1`.

Comment: @DarkAtom Fixed. Sorry, was rushed

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){
    
    long long int creditcard;

    printf("Credit Card Number: ");
    scanf("%lli", &creditcard);


    printf("%lli", creditcard);
}
```

this will work.

EDIT: As stated in the comments, if you have leading zeros, this won't work. Instead taking it as string like above is better.

Comment: While this solves the immediate problem asked, it will not solve the problem of storing credit card numbers. Remember that credit cart numbers can have leading zeros, something which any integer type will not have. Also, sometimes it's useful to group the digits in some way, or to access then one by one, in which case integer types also makes it much harder. Same goes for phone-numbers.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are generally frowned upon, since they tend to lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is bad. In the future please explain what was wrong, how it can be fixed, and then *maybe* show some small example code how to do it.